# linux pthread_mutex_lock only works in the second try

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, posix

Edit: I'm attaching a snippet, I've initialized attr, and all calls were good.

I've been trying to use a mutex with PRIO_PROTECT, but first call returns EINVAL, while second call returns zero\success.
here's what I've done:

```
pthread_mutexattr_setprioceiling(&attr, 99);
pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol(&attr, PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT);
pthread_mutex_init(&plock, &attr);
pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attr);
ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&plock);  //now ret == EINVAL
ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&plock);  // ret == 0
```

I understand that EINVAL means that the caller priority is higher than the ceiling, so I have 2 questions:

1. why does it work on the second try?
2. How to lower the thread's priority to the ceiling? or rather, set the ceiling to the thread's priority?

Comment: have you checked returned values from these calls: pthread_mutexattr_setprioceiling, pthread_mutex_init, pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol?

Answer (score 3):

A call to `pthread_mutexattr_init` is missing.

---

[`PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutexattr_getprotocol.3p.html) means:

> When a thread owns one or more non-robust mutexes initialized with
>          the PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT protocol, **it shall execute at the higher of
>          its priority or the highest of the priority ceilings** of all the non-robust mutexes owned by this thread and initialized with this
>          attribute, regardless of whether other threads are blocked on any of
>          these non-robust mutexes or not.

Which means that `pthread_mutex_lock` sets the priority of the current thread to `max(current_priority, prioceiling)`. Your `prioceiling` is 99 and such a priority requires a thread with real-time scheduling class (FIFO or round-robin).

In fact, any priority for [`pthread_mutexattr_setprioceiling`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getprioceiling.html) requires a real-time scheduling class:

> The values of `prioceiling` are within the maximum range of priorities defined by `SCHED_FIFO`.

This is because the functions you'd like to use belong to [POSIX realtime extensions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/realtime.html) and the default [scheduling class `SCHED_OTHER` is there for](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_08_04_05):

> This policy is defined to allow strictly conforming applications to be able to indicate in a portable manner that they no longer need a realtime scheduling policy.

If you run your application with `sudo chrt --fifo 1 <app>` it assigns your process FIFO scheduling class of priority 1 which makes it succeed in locking the mutex on the first call.

---

Regarding why the 2nd call succeeds when the 1st one fails, that seems to be undocumented behaviour, if I am not mistaken, and is [probably a bug in glibc](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25943).

Comment: Thanks, I tought it might be the FIFO, but didn't know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to bump the current executing code priority or simply protect some data.

If simply trying to protect some data...

```
pthread_mutex_t  myMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

then when wanting to use the mutex:

```
pthread_mutex_lock( &myMutex );
... // manipulate the 'critical' data
```

Then when ready to allow another thread to access that same data.

```
... // finished manipulation of the 'critical' data
pthread_mutex_unlock( &myMutex );
```

Note: there are other values for the initialization, but the above macro value is the most common.